# Message and Aliases

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was developing on my bot the other day and I was wondering if I could create aliases on a message For example Me: "ping", bot: "Pong!", so what I wanted to do is make so I can say: p and the bot will still respond with Pong!
I am using this code:

```
client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content === 'ping') {
        msg.lineReplyNoMention('Pong!');
    } 
});
```

If I can create aliases on this code please tell me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a list of aliases and use [`Array#includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if the `msg.content` is in that array:

```js
let pingCommands = ['ping', 'p']
let msg = {}

msg.content = 'p'
if (pingCommands.includes(msg.content))
  console.log(msg.content, 'Pong!')

msg.content = 'pong'
if (pingCommands.includes(msg.content))
  console.log(msg.content, 'Pong!')

msg.content = 'ping'
if (pingCommands.includes(msg.content))
  console.log(msg.content, 'Pong!')

msg.content = 'penge'
if (pingCommands.includes(msg.content))
  console.log(msg.content, 'Pong!')
```

Your code should look like this:

```js
client.on('message', msg => {
  let pingCommands = ['ping', 'p']
  if (pingCommands.includes(msg.content)) {
    msg.lineReplyNoMention('Pong!');
  } 
});
```